# MySQL server keeps crashing

Tags: mysql, linux, lamp

Hi need serious help here.

mysql server keep crashing continuously and i can connect to mysql intermittently for a few seconds at most. I didn't change any server configuration recently, it happened all of sudden.

Please help!

Below is the mysql logs.

```
Version: '5.5.40-cll-lve'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL) by Atomicorp
18:39:51 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=8388608
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=1
max_threads=151
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 338554 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x21a8080
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 7f1104495d98 thread_stack 0x40000
/usr/libexec/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x2e)[0x79368e]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x493)[0x67b8a3]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf500)[0x7f1108bbd500]
/lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35)[0x7f11070098a5]
/lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x175)[0x7f110700b085]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x707b7)[0x7f11070477b7]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x760e6)[0x7f110704d0e6]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(_ZN16Security_context7destroyEv+0xb4)[0x5622b4]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(_ZN3THDD1Ev+0x13d)[0x565e2d]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(_ZN3THDD0Ev+0x9)[0x566209]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(_Z10unlink_thdP3THD+0xfa)[0x5183fa]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(_Z29one_thread_per_connection_endP3THDb+0x16)[0x518466]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(_Z24do_handle_one_connectionP3THD+0x139)[0x620479]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(handle_one_connection+0x5b)[0x62055b]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7851)[0x7f1108bb5851]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f11070bf90d]

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (0): is an invalid pointer
Connection ID (thread ID): 1
Status: KILL_CONNECTION

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
141024 14:39:51 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
141024 14:39:51 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
141024 14:39:51 [Note] libgovernor.so not found
141024 14:39:51 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
141024 14:39:51 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
141024 14:39:51 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
141024 14:39:51 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
141024 14:39:51 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
141024 14:39:51 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
141024 14:39:51 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
141024 14:39:51 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
141024 14:39:51  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
141024 14:39:52  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
141024 14:39:53 InnoDB: 5.5.40 started; log sequence number 67891929
141024 14:39:53 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
141024 14:39:53 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
141024 14:39:53 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
141024 14:39:53 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_current' has the wrong structure
141024 14:39:53 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_history' has the wrong structure
141024 14:39:53 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_history_long' has the wrong structure
141024 14:39:53 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'setup_consumers' has the wrong structure
141024 14:39:53 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'setup_instruments' has the wrong structure
141024 14:39:53 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'setup_timers' has the wrong structure
141024 14:39:53 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'performance_timers' has the wrong structure
141024 14:39:53 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'threads' has the wrong structure
141024 14:39:53 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_summary_by_thread_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
141024 14:39:53 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_summary_by_instance' has the wrong structure
141024 14:39:53 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_summary_global_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
141024 14:39:53 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'file_summary_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
141024 14:39:53 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'file_summary_by_instance' has the wrong structure
141024 14:39:53 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'mutex_instances' has the wrong structure
141024 14:39:53 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'rwlock_instances' has the wrong structure
141024 14:39:53 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'cond_instances' has the wrong structure
141024 14:39:53 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'file_instances' has the wrong structure
141024 14:39:53 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.40-cll-lve'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL) by Atomicorp
18:39:53 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.
```

Comment: Consider upgrading your *mysql*. Also test your hardware. Check your latest backups. You could need them.

Comment: +1 for version upgrade. It doesn't look as corruption though - Innodb is pretty aggressive to unexpected data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THanks to both.

Yes, upgrade did fix the issue for me.